# Determining the running time for recurrence relation T(n) = T(n-1)+n

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, recurrence, big-o

How do I determine the running time (in terms of Big-Theta) for the algorithm of input size `n` that satisfies recurrence relation `T(n) = T(n-1)+n` where `n >= 1` and with initial condition `T(1) = 1`?

Edit: I was practicing a past exam paper. Got stuck on this question. Need guidance

Comment: No this is not a homework question. This is one of the questions in the past exam paper that I was given to practice as a preparation for an exam in future. I was just stuck on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it this way: `T(n) = T(n-1) + n = T(n-2) + (n-1) + n = T(n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n`. Which means if n >= 1 then you will get something like T(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n. If you work out the pattern of this series you will see that `(n+1)n/2`. Therefore, `Ө(n^2)`

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful!